# Response is passed but it alert as failed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

> can i read line number 2nd  //this is the data given back to cart.php

```
response
//Line number
1<!DOCTYPE html>
2passed      //i want to read this line
```

> this is my javascript

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url : '/tutorial/admin/parsers/check_address.php',
        method : 'POST',
        data : data,
        success : function(Response) {
            if($.trim(Response) != 'passed'){ //evry time it is exicuting this condition 
                jQuery('#payment-errors').html(Response);
                alert('failed');
            }
            if($.trim(Response == 'passed')){
           alert('[passed'); 
           }
```

> i just need any solution on this so i can work on it

Comment: show us what console.log(data) is at response

Comment: depends on what response type you are sending. As @KAD mentioned check what are you getting in response. If its an object you need to convert it into string using `toString()`, or mention proper response type e.g. `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: keep exit or die at the end of the code of php

Comment: i have added my content of console